# Replace letter with number in python after defining function

Tags: python

I was searching for this, but didn't really find a similar answer yet (I'm new here so, pardon if my search skills are not that refined yet).

Basically what I want to know is how to create numbers after defining some variables. For example, I define a = 1 and b = 2, and I want to create an integer by entering any random combination of a and b, let's say - aabb, so that it prints 1122, or abab which prints for me 1212 etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you done any research for something like "Python randomly choosing value" or "Python generate combinations" ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to create a mapping between characters. You can use `str.maketrans` and `str.translate` for this purpose. `str.maketrans` just returns a dictionary which maps the ordinal values of the characters in the first string to the ordinal values of the characters in the second string.

```
mapping = str.maketrans("ab", "12")

print("aabbabab".translate(mapping))
```

Output:

```
11221212
>>>
```

Comment: Does this assume the possibility to change a and b, because it seems that this one assignes ab as 12 by default.

I would need so ething where, let's say 

a = 1
b = 2

define function f1 as random combination of a and b, so when I enter f1(aabb) the output is 1122. After that I can go and define a = 5 and the same code should give the output 5522.